# Determine whether each of the following functions is one-to-one and whether it is onto

Tags: proof-verification, equivalence-relations, congruence-relations

$$f: Z \longrightarrow Z_7, f(k)=[k]$$

$$f: Z \longrightarrow Z_8, f(k)=[k]$$

I think this can't be one-to-one at all since it repeats after 6, and since each $f(k)$ value has a value $k$, then it is onto. However, it's the same reason for these two functions, so I'm not sure if there is something different about them aside from the modulo.

edit: To be a little more clearer, he provides these functions as well:

$$f: Z \longrightarrow Z_7, f(k)=[2k]$$

$$f: Z \longrightarrow Z_8, f(k)=[2k]$$

These two are different since it is multiples of 2, so some classes cannot be reached, such as [1], so it is neither one-to-one nor onto.

Comment: If $[k]$ is the equivalence class of $k$ (its value mod $7$ or mod $8$) then you are right that both functions are onto and neither is one-to-one. You're right to be puzzled since both have the same answer for the same reason, so why ask both. Are you sure you have the question right?

Comment: Yes, it came right off my paper. There are two more functions that he includes that are slightly different if that would help?

Comment: You can edit the question to put in the other two, include your answers to all four, and add a proof-verification tag.

Comment: It has been edited and clarified. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost. Three of your four answers are right. But you should examine the map
from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_7$ that sends $k$ to $ 2k \pmod{7}$ a little more carefully. It's small enough to compute by brute force.

Comment: I completely missed [8] which is equivalent to [1], [10] which is equivalent to [3], [12] which is equivalent to [5]. So this means it is onto but still not one-to-one since it restarts, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.